# Angular & Firebase comparar IDs de colecciones distintas y si es igual mostrar

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

les hago una consulta sobre Angular y Firebase.

En este caso estoy creando documentos en una coleccion de `[Cupones]`, dichos cupones tienen su `"ID"`, y tengo otra coleccion de `[usuarios]`, los cuales cuando dan click en optener un cupon se envia a una subcoleccion de `[usuarios]`, llamada `[miscupones]`, donde guarda el `"ID"` de dicho `"(cupon)"` clickeado, ejemplo: Foto 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo que usar dos imagenes para mostrar todo el recorrido de la base de datos:
Foto2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, tambien se crea un campo llamado `obtenido: true`, con este campo, y el `cuponid: (ID DEL CUPON)` me gustaria mostrar una lista de los cupones que obtuvo el usuario, creeria que existe un modo de comparar dichos IDs y decir que si el `ID de la coleccion usuarios/miscuopnes/cuponid: ID, es igual al  ID de la coleccion cupones: ID, y de ser iguales mostrarlos`, les paso una foto del cupon obtenido para que vean que es el mismo id:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos cordiales!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del `CombineLatest` de rxjs, aquí se encuentran una buena explicación:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

## Solución

1. Obtener todos los cupones por usuario ( Consultar la colección mis cupones del usuario 'XYZ' ) filtrando por la propiedad `obtenido === true`.
2. Lo anterior te dará un array de objetos con las propiedades `{canjeado: boolean, cuponid: string, obtenido:true }`
3. Debes recorrer todo el array, y por cada uno de ellos llama un método que te obtenga los cupones. Algo así como, `obtenerCuponPorId(idCupon)`, este método te devolverá un observable.
4. Guardar todo esto en un nueva variable llamada `obs` -> Array de observables
5. En este punto, puedes hacer uso del combineLatest y hacer un map sobre ellos para crear el objeto que necesitas:
   `combineLatest(obs).map()`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta Sebastian, voy a leer un poco la documentacion que me enviaste para ver si logro solucionarlo!

Comment: Hola Sebastian, le verdad es que soy novato, eh llegado bastante lejos con este proyecto, pero no logro mostrar dichos cupones, te molestaria mucho ponerme algun codigo de ejemplo?, o si necesitas parte del mio lo podria compartir por aca, saludos!

Comment: Sí, puedes compartir parte del código sería estupendo y así poderte ayudar más a fondo con esta consulta.